# The Sum of Sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am looking up Niven http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183516304 . I have something elementary to ask.

Now, $A(n) $ denotes the number of integers of A which are not greater than $n$ and

$d(A) = glb \frac{A(n)}{n} $

In $[3]$ "The Sum of Sets", it is stated that the conjecture of Khinchtine was proved by Mann which states $ d(A+B) \geq d(A) + d(B) $ or $ d(A+B) =1 $ where $A+B$ is the sum of two sequences $A$ and $B$ such that $ a \in A $ and $ b \in B$. (I can not find this on google).

How are the two equivalent? Also, $d(A+B)$ could be less than 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no claim of equivalence. The result says that at least one of the following holds: (i) $d(A+B)\ge d(A)+d(B)$ or (ii) $d(A+B)=1$.

In other words,

if $d(A)+d(B)\lt 1$, then $d(A+B)\ge d(A)+d(B)$;

if $d(A)+d(B)\ge 1$, then $d(A+B)=1$.

Comment: Yes, thats right. Thank You. (There is an 'or' there). My bad.. Do you know where one can look up its proof?

Comment: The simplification of Mann's proof of the alpha-beta theorem by Peter Scherk and Artin is behind a pay wall. I think there have been later simplifications.